# Bin folder missing in vscode directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

Tried to run vscode on my terminal as usual but now it gives me an error saying that the function does not exists so, I visit my environment variables and can still see the path for the vscode function. but when I visit vscode directory, the 'bin' folder disappeared:

[image]

Tried to add it without the '/bin' but every time I use 'code' function on my terminal it works but it leaves this, which is kind of annoying:

[image]